# Why insertAfter/ insertBefore don't work in dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery

My comments are loaded dynamically. When I post comments the `insertAfter/ insertBefore` wont work. Rest of things are working fine. Comments are going database to via ajax post request, console logs and alerts are showing result but only InsertAfter isn't responding and there are no errors in console log.

**Not working**

```
newcomment.insertAfter(respond);
```

**Working**

```
$('#respond').append(newcomment);
```

For now I'm using `append` but I'm curious about it. Is it jQuery bug or I'm doing it wrong?

**EDIT**

I changed it to `newcomment.insertAfter('#respond');` and now its working.

Comment: are you using [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Comment: You know that those don't insert the element in the same place? One inserts the element **after** `#respond` in the DOM, the other appends the element at the bottom **inside** `#respond`, and both should work fine with dynamic content as long as the content is in the DOM when you're doing this.

Comment: The difference is the working selection selects the new respond element, where as the not working one tries to reuse one that was replaced. This is not a bug, it's simply a logic error.