# jQuery insertBefore not working for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert an element before another dynamically created element?

I'm basically creating child elements using `$('#numbers').append('<div name="x" />');`

```
<div id="numbers">
    <div name="0" />
    <div name="2" />
</div>
```

Then I want to use `insertBefore()` to add `<div name="1" />` between the two child elements, by doing

```
$('<div name="1" />').insertBefore( $('#numbers div').eq(1) );
```

However, it keeps adding the new element last. I've also tried using `before()`, but it seems to make no difference. Maybe `insertBefore()` doesn't work with dynamically created elements, but what is the alternative?

I considered `append()` and `prepend()`, but that just nests the new div further.

I think my problem is similar to this question (still unsolved) [Why insertAfter/ insertBefore don't work in dynamically loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490637/why-insertafter-insertbefore-dont-work-in-dynamically-loaded-content)

Comment: There's no problem, the code you used works.

Comment: I have created codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PzaQaw and it works fine

Comment: i see syntax error on closing div tag

Comment: In which order are the the element inserted in your dom? What are your trying to achieve in general?

Comment: If `$('<div name="1" />').insertBefore( $('#numbers div').eq(1) );` is executed before there is an element matching `$('#numbers div').eq(1)` it will not work

Comment: In generall it should be working: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/emax6kdz/) try changing the `0` to `1`

Comment: @empiric it works and tested in codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PzaQaw

Comment: @NagaSaiA please read my comment carefully again.In your html the elements are already existing, so there is a element matching `$('#numbers div').eq(1)`. Remove the div containing `222` and it will not work anymore. That's why I ask about the order the elements are getting added.

Comment: I must agree that the example I created seems to work fine (should probably have tested that beforehand). My real code is more complex, so the culprit must lie elsewhere. Thank you all for your input and sorry for the inconvenience.